# How to generate csv file in bi publisher

Tags: oracle, csv, bi-publisher, fusion

How can I remove column headers when generating csv file ('|' delimeter) in bi publisher in oracle fusion?

eText will remove the column headers but it generate text file. When output type is selected as CSV, then it bypasses the etext template and generates data from the data model.

Comment: Can you give examples of what output you are seeing, the configuration, and then what you are expecting?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got a workaround solution for this which is working perfectly.